# Marginal Spacing in Curriculum Vitae

Tags: currvita, curve-class

I have the following minimal example for a curriculum vitae:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{curve}
\usepackage{currvita}



\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  \put(440,610){\includegraphics[width=39mm]{sherlock.jpg}}%
}

\begin{cv}{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{cvlist}{Personal Details}
\item[Name:] Big Boss
\item[Phone:] 0123456789
\item[Email:] neruj@mailzi.ru
\item[Born:] 23.November 2015, Malibu (Beach)
\item[Status:] single
\end{cvlist}

\begin {cvlist}{Soft Skills}
\item[EDV:] Word, Excel, Python, TeX, SQL
\item[Sports:] National Hockey League Stanley Midwest Cup Playoffs 2015
\end{cvlist}


\cvplace{Miami}
\date{23.11.2015}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Sports line is limited by a relatively big margin, how could I decrease the margins and force it into one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) makes it easy to change the page layout parameters. You probably just need to insert

```
\usepackage[a4paper,width=16cm]{geometry}
```

in your preamble, and then experiment to get the best width for your cv (don't make it too wide, or you may strain the eyes of the person reading it).